# Converting an SVG to Ext.draw.Component Gradient

Tags: extjs, svg

Suppose I have an SVG file and I would like to make it an Ext.draw.Component, how do I make my SVG stop-opacity translate to the Ext.draw.Component Item?

For example, from the **SVG file**, I would have something like so:

```
<linearGradient ="linearGradient2920">
  <stop
     id="stop2922"
     style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="0" />
  <stop
     id="stop2924"
     style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0"
     offset="1" />
</linearGradient>
```

What would it look like in the **Ext.draw.Component**? Would it translate like so?

```
gradients: [{
            {
            id: 'linearGradient2920',
            angle: 100,
            stops: {
                0: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    opacity: 100 //<---Is this even valid??
                },
                100: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    opactiy: 0 //<---Is this even valid??
                }
            }
        }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this in the source code for Ext.js for SVG - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Svg.html

```
for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
            stop = gradient.stops[i];
            stopEl = me.createSvgElement("stop");
            stopEl.setAttribute("offset", stop.offset + "%");
            stopEl.setAttribute("stop-color", stop.color);
            stopEl.setAttribute("stop-opacity",stop.opacity);
            gradientEl.appendChild(stopEl);
        }
```

Note the **stop.opacity**. This seems to indicate it should be valid to use opacity like in the original post, however I am not sure if it is on a scale of 1.0 or 100.

Comment: stop-opacity is either 0..1 or 0%..100%, see spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#StopOpacityProperty